# Analogues $apply or $digest(Angular) in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Is there any analogues functions $apply or $digest in Aurelia ?
How immediately call changes bindingValue?

My case:
I have tree(each node contain list of item, screen 1). I have parent component(names: tree), and node component(names:node).
Each node have a toggle button. When i'm toggle my items parent component should know how changes content height.

```
toggleNode(event) {
    for (var i = 0, length = this.current.children.length; i < length;  i++) {
        this.current.children[i].visible = !this.current.children[i].visible;
    }
   //some code 
   this.evAggregator.publish("toggle-agents", event);
}
```

View:

```
<ol show.bind="current.visible">//Some markup</ol>
```

My parent component catch this event and check content  size:

```
@autoinject
export class Agents {
  constructor(private evAggregator: EventAggregator) {
    this.toggleAgentsSubscriber = this.evAggregator.subscribe("toggle-  agents", (e) => {
      //some code for recalculate content height
    });
  }
```

}

Now code execute that:
  1)  this.current.children[i].visible = false(when node collapse)
  2)  Fire my event "toggle-agents"
  3)  Subscriber catch my event (recalculate height)
  4)  In depth at Aurelia ObserverLocator update my (visible property) in DOM and height changes.

I need:
  1) this.current.children[i].visible = false(when node collapse)
  2) In depth at Aurelia ObserverLocator update my (visible property) in DOM and height changes.
  3) Fire my custom event.
  4) Subscriber catch my event and recalculate height when height content actually changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Aurelia, changes are immediately applied for the most part. Aurelia only uses dirty checking for computed properties (properties with a getter function). If you wanted to manually invoke the dirty-checking, you could do something like this:

```js
import {DirtyChecker} from 'aurelia-binding';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';

@inject(DirtyChecker)
export class Foo {
  constructor(dirtyChecker) {
    dirtyChecker.check(); // force an application-wide dirty check
  }
}
```

In practice, this sort of thing is never needed in an Aurelia app.  If you have specific bindings that you want to force to update you can use the `signal` binding behavior:

```html
<template>
  <label>${foo & signal:'my signal name'}</label>
</template>
```

```js
import {BindingSignaler} from 'aurelia-templating-resources';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';

@inject(BindingSignaler)
export class Foo {
  constructor(signaler) {
    signaler.signal('my signal name'); // evaluate any bindings with 'my signal name'
  }
}
```

Try to stay away from these two techniques if you can. If you're using this for something other than time-based bindings (binding to something that uses `Date.now()` or `new Date()`) or internationalization locale-changed events... you might not be doing it the "Aurelia way".

Comment: I'm tried use signal technique but it's not yielded results. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I'm added description of my case.